# Cannot find elements within directive templateUrl, in link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my directive code:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var autumnDirectives;

  autumnDirectives = angular.module('autumnDirectives', []);

  autumnDirectives.directive('timeline', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        timeline: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/timeline/_timeline.html',
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        return console.log($scope.timeline);
      },
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        console.log(el);
        return console.log(el.find(".item"));
      }
    };
  });

}).call(this);
```

my template:

```
<div class="timeline clearfix">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in timeline">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="content">{{ item.content }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="connect_line"></div><div class="connect_line"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the jqlite find does not return the item element (length 0) -or any element for that matter. If I append an element in the link function then I am able to find it, however otherwise no.

When I log el, it returns the correct element, and if I venture into children with chromes inspect tool I am able to find .item.

I thought that link was called once the template was ready? Is something going wrong here, or am I not understanding something?

Otherwise everything works fine

Thanks

NOTE: I am able to find the first div in the hierarchy with the `.timeline` class, but nothing at a deeper level

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Yes I have jquery included

Comment: Is it included before angular.js?

Comment: Yes it is included before angular.

Comment: Maybe when the link function is  running ,  `timeline` is still not populated on the outer scope. please put `console.log(scope.timeline)` inside your linking function to see.

Comment: I think you might be on to something, it seems to only be an issue with the ng-repeat (.item) div... how can i have it so my link code only runs when its populated, a watch or something? Also how would I debug this? Thanks!

Comment: You should post the code where you populate `timeline` at the outer scope

Answer (score 4):

You should run it inside `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function(){
  console.log(el.find(".item"));
})
```

What happens is that `ngRepeat` registers a $watchCollection with a callback.
When a $digest happen , that callback clones the DOM elements.
Before that $digest no DOM elements are available.
$timeout run after a $digest so we can safely refer the DOM elements.

I made a plunker to check when elements are loaded to the DOM : http://plnkr.co/edit/X8PuOQhhbQB3Gv657R35?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You're generating your `.item` with `ng-repeat`. At the time, `ng-repeat` directive is not finished rendering.

At that time, the HTML looks like this: (using `console.log(el[0].outerHTML)`)

```
<div timeline="" class="ng-isolate-scope">
   <div class="timeline clearfix">
     <!-- ngRepeat: item in timeline -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Khanh how can I have my link code run when it is ready?

Comment: @Melbourne2991: You should not. When working with an MVC framework like angular js, the view should be `as passive as possible` and should not be listened to. Think again about your code design. You could do it another way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This solves my problem: `   scope.$watch('timeline', (newValue, OldValue) ->
    if newValue.length > 0
     # console.log(newValue)
   )` , is there something wrong with this? surely there are instances where you would need to perform dom manipulations on elements within a ng-repeat div? Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: @Melbourne2991: yes, you should only listen for changes to your modal.   That `should be the solution`. I cannot confirm because I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: My guess is that `ng-repeat` has not even start rendering at the time the linking function run. post linking functions of child elements run before post linking function of the parent element. The data is just not populated yet.

Comment: @Ilan Frumer: as we can see,at that time, `ng-repeat` is already transformed but is not fully rendered.

Comment: @Ilan Frumer: I read in a book about angular. Angular translates directives in 3 steps: Transforms the DOM based on the directive’s
rules (template, replace, transclude, and so on) => compile => link . In this case, I think only the first step is performed

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to write a directive for "item" and use the link function of it.